# Flexigrid Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, flexigrid

I don't know how to use Flexigrid jQuery in my website, please answer me sir.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [Google Groups](http://groups.google.com/group/flexigrid/)

It's specifically for help on implementation and usage.